# datetime row created

Tags: sql-server, date, time

I have sqlserver DB , and there I have few tables.

I have 1 table that not save each row what is the datetime the each row created.

1. Is there any way to know when which row was created?
2. Is there any way (without changing the application that created the row
   on this db, I can't add any SP to do it) that from now, when the
   row is created, it will automatically add the created dateTime?

Comment: 1) No. 2) Yes. Specify DBMS.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, you can't get data that isn't stored in your system. There is no way to know the date from which each row was inserted or updated if you don't have it stored somewhere.

For the second question, you can create a new column with a default constraint that will automatically set the current datetime value (if it wasn't supplied by the client), or an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that updates this column also. On both cases you need a column to store this value.

```
ALTER TABLE SchemaName.YourTable ADD CreatedDate DATETIME
```

- Using a constraint with default value:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE SchemaName.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SchemaNameYourTable_CreatedDate 
  DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR CreatedDate
  ```
- Using a trigger:

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER SchemaName.utrYourTableUpdateCreatedDate ON SchemaName.YourTable
      AFTER INSERT
  AS
  BEGIN

      UPDATE T SET
          CreatedDate = GETDATE()
      FROM
          inserted AS I -- special table that holds only new inserted rows (in this case)
          INNER JOIN SchemaName.YourTable AS T ON I.KeyColumn = T.KeyColumn

  END
  ```